# Any perks to getting 100% on Assassins Creed 4?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I was just wondering if there is anything like a special item or upgrade you get for 100% the game, haven't finished the game fully yet so no spoilers please!

Answer (score 3):

Completing the Abstergo challenges **unlocks cheats** (unlimited ammo, invincible, always drunk, etc). As far as I know there aren't any special outfits or weapons for getting 100%, aside from the ones you would pick up along the way from **finding collectibles** and **completing side quests**.

**UPDATE:** You receive a **multiplayer emblem** when you complete 100% of the challenges. Thank you [Nolanar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/46740/nolonar).

Comment: You get a multiplayer emblem when you complete 100% of the challenges.